# When can I omit self

Tags: python, class, tkinter, self

I found this example of a simple tkinter class.
The example works with either

'frame' or 'self.frame'

Why can or would I safely omit 'self'?

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = Button(
            frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit
            )
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

    def say_hi(self):
        print "hi there, everyone!"

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
root.destroy() # optional; see description below
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's more efficient to use a local variable like `frame` rather than an object attribute like `self.frame`. You should only use an object attribute when you need to be able to refer to the object after the method that created it returns.

In Python, objects that are stored in local variables get garbage-collected once the function or method returns, but that's not a problem here. The Frame object itself will be persistent because it's linked to the master object you pass to `__init__()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit `self` for most case, except for `self.say_hi`. Otherwise, `say_hi` references global function, not a method.

```
def __init__(self, master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()

    button = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
    button.pack(side=LEFT)

    hi_there = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
    hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)
```

`self.frame` / `frame` both can be used as long as the frame object is referenced only in a method. If it is used in another method, it should be qualified as `self.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit `self` before `frame` because you pass in reference to it into the `Button` which gets stored as `self.button` (presumably `Button` holds a reference to the frame for you).

This ensures that your `frame` will not be garbage collected onece you're out of scope of `__init__` as only objects that are not referred anywhere get destroyed.

In this example you have no use for `frame` outside of `self.button` so no point storing additional reference to it in `self.frame`.

As mentioned in other answers you only need `self` if you will want to reference something directly later in relation to your object instance.