# Functions still works despite there are same variables names in the code

Tags: python, radio-button

I came across this style of creating UI and thought I had tried it out with some radio buttons.

Basically I created 2 functions - `testButtons01Group` and `testButtons02Group` that caters to 3 radio buttons each. However I had thought I will expect some error say if I clicked onto `Grp02` push button, seeing that I named all 6 radio buttons in the same conventions but yet it is still working as per normal.

Why is this so?
Also, just wondering in this code style i wrote, is it feasible, or will it cause any confusions?

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class mainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.testButtons01Group(), 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.testButtons02Group(), 2, 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.setWindowTitle("Radio Buttons Test")
        self.resize(480, 200)


    def testButtons01Group(self):
        groupBox = QGroupBox("Group 01")
        self.testBtn01 = QPushButton('Grp01')

        self.radioBtn1 = QRadioButton("Button01")
        self.radioBtn2 = QRadioButton("Button02")
        self.radioBtn3 = QRadioButton("Button03")
        self.radioBtn1.setChecked(True)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.radioBtn1)
        hbox.addWidget(self.radioBtn2)
        hbox.addWidget(self.radioBtn3)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.testBtn01)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        groupBox.setLayout(vbox)

        # Connections
        self.connect(self.testBtn01, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.testBtn01_pushBtn)

        return groupBox


    def testButtons02Group(self):
        groupBox = QGroupBox("Group 02")
        self.testBtn02 = QPushButton('Grp02')

        self.radioBtn1 = QRadioButton("Button01")
        self.radioBtn2 = QRadioButton("Button02")
        self.radioBtn3 = QRadioButton("Button03")
        self.radioBtn1.setChecked(True)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.radioBtn1)
        hbox.addWidget(self.radioBtn2)
        hbox.addWidget(self.radioBtn3)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.testBtn02)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        groupBox.setLayout(vbox)

        # Connections
        self.connect(self.testBtn02, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.testBtn02_pushBtn)

        return groupBox


    def testBtn01_pushBtn(self, *args):
        print "Test Button is pushed"
        self.testBtn01_Funcs()


    def testBtn01_Funcs(self):

        if self.radioBtn1.isChecked():
            print ">>> Group01 Radio Button 1 selected"

        elif self.radioBtn2.isChecked():
            print ">>> Group01 Radio Button 2 selected"

        else:
            print ">>> Group01 Radio Button 3 selected"



    def testBtn02_pushBtn(self, *args):
        print "Test Button is pushed"
        self.testBtn02_Funcs()


    def testBtn02_Funcs(self):

        if self.radioBtn1.isChecked():
            print ">>> Group02 Radio Button 1 selected"

        elif self.radioBtn2.isChecked():
            print ">>> Group02 Radio Button 2 selected"

        else:
            print ">>> Group02 Radio Button 3 selected"




def main():
    global app 
    global form
    app = qApp
    form = mainWindow()
    form.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Greatly appreciated for any advice

Comment: definitely not the best practice, im not even sure why it gives you 6 different buttons with your naming.

Comment: @chris Hey... It did not gives me 6 different buttons as I created them out myself. And I thought why not give them the same variable name in `testButtons02Group` (sometimes I tend to copy and paste similar functions) but it surprises that it works.. So I take it that the UI style is a no go?

Comment: I think I see why its working, it works fine as you say, but I personally would for say dont use the same variable names, espeically if they are referencing self. Its nice that under the hood Qt deals somehow figures out that self.btn1 in one function is a a different self.btn1 in another fucntion, but it is very confusing.

Comment: It's preferred that you put relevant code into the question and not just link to an external site; that pastebin code may no longer exist in a couple of years when someone else is looking at this question.

Comment: @chris It seems this is due to `self.connect` statement that I have insert into the two separately... Guess I will stick back to my code style rather than this current one I have used. Just thought that this style is neater..

Comment: @PM2Ring Edited my question, posted the actual code instead from external site

Answer (score 0):

I don't have PyQt so I can't test your code, but I'd be *very* surprised if it *really* works properly. In particular, I suspect that the tests in `testBtn01_Funcs()` will actually give results that relate to the second button group, not the first group.

OTOH, the button creation phase should work ok - it's a similar situation as to what we discussed in [this tkinter question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27374541/4014959) yesterday. But for your GUI you *do* need separate object attributes for each button since you want to query their status after they've been created.

I'm not familiar with Qt - I normally use GTK for my GUIs, and in GTK the radiobutton callback function gets passed the radiobutton that received the signal as the first arg, so you don't need to keep references to each button if you don't want to; maybe Qt has a similar feature.

Comment: `testBtn01_Funcs()` actually gives results to the first button group, likewise the same for `testBtn02_Funcs()` which gives results to the second button group. (My print statement says so)

Comment: @dissidia: Ah, ok. I guess Qt is doing something magical to figure out which radio buttons are actually part of a group, but I don't know enough about Qt to make further intelligent comments. :) PS. Thanks for pasting your code into the question.

Comment: Yea.. I am still trying to figure out how it does that :p

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing really wrong with that style of creating GUI items, but there are some problems with how you are naming things. Giving each set of radio buttons the same attribute names means you will only be able to refer to the second set (because the first set gets over-written).

The reason why the GUI creation functions work, is because the widgets are all added to layouts. This will automatically re-parent each widget (if they don't already have a parent), so that will be enough to keep all the widgets alive.

However, one problem remains: how do you access the radio-buttons once the GUI has been created? There are several ways to do this, but one way to do it would be re-write your code as follows.

Firstly, keep references to the group-boxes that contain the buttons:

```
    self.groupBox01 = self.testButtons01Group()
    self.groupBox02 = self.testButtons02Group()
    grid.addWidget(self.groupBox01, 1, 0)
    grid.addWidget(self.groupBox02, 2, 0)
```

Secondly, keep *all* the widgets in the function scope when creating them, rather than setting attributes:

```
def testButtons01Group(self):
    groupBox = QGroupBox("Group 01")
    testBtn = QPushButton('Grp01')

    radioBtn1 = QRadioButton("Button01")
    radioBtn2 = QRadioButton("Button02")
    radioBtn3 = QRadioButton("Button03")
    radioBtn1.setChecked(True)

    hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    hbox.addWidget(radioBtn1)
    hbox.addWidget(radioBtn2)
    hbox.addWidget(radioBtn3)

    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(testBtn)
    vbox.addLayout(hbox)
    vbox.addStretch(1)
    groupBox.setLayout(vbox)

    testBtn.clicked.connect(self.testBtn01_pushBtn)

    return groupBox
```

And finally, use the group-box to access the buttons you're interested in:

```
def testBtn01_Funcs(self):
    for radioBtn in self.groupBox01.findChildren(QRadioButton):
        if radioBtn.isChecked():
            print ">>> Group01 %s selected" % radioBtn.text()
            break
```

(Obviously, you will also need to do the same thing for the other button group).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I will try out your methods later on and see where it goes. I have 2 questions. 1. Regarding the first part, how is this - `grid.addWidget(self.testButtons01Group(), 1, 0)` different from this - `grid.addWidget(self.groupBox01, 1, 0)`? 2. About keeping the widgets within function scopes, why is setting attributes a bad idea?

Comment: (1) It keeps a reference to the groupbox as an attribute so it can be accessed later. (2) It's not a bad idea, but I think it's more consistent to do it that way (because it keeps everything local to the function). Having said all that, I don't think I would necessarily advocate this style of setting up the GUI. I prefer to do as much as I can in Qt Designer, which results in all the widgets becoming attributes of the main window. This seems more Pythonic to me, whereas the above style seems more in keeping with C++.

Comment: I'm confused. :) dissidia claims that their original `testBtn01_Funcs()` correctly reports the status of the first button group, but I can't see how it can do that since `self.radioBtn1` etc get over-written when the second group of buttons get created. And I _think_ you (ekhumoro) agree with me...

Comment: @PM2Ring. I don't think you are at all confused - dissidia is mistaken about the status of the first set of buttons. I think it may help to know that the code in the question seems to have been (partly) taken from the [Group Box example in the Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-groupbox.html), which doesn't cover signal handling. My answer is an attempt to deal with the signal handling issues in a way that is consistent with the original Qt example.

Comment: Thanks, ekhumoro. I don't have PyQT so I can't test dissidia's code. But I'm puzzled that they insist that `testBtn01_Funcs()` correctly reports the status of the first button group. Maybe dissidia should do some more thorough testing...